# Neural network filtering out everything else than cats/dogs

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

The question is simple, however I cannot find solution:

How to recognise cats and dogs and filter out everything other?

Another words: I have a big database with images of cats and dogs and all other photos mixed together, is there a way to say in output: cat -or- dog -or- something else?

Either CNNs are not constructed to do such things efficiently?

I'm using python / Keras / Tensorflow; solution with finding cats / dogs when I provide images of cats and dogs only - works fine.

Comment: Just label the the something else it's own class and do three class classification. That would be one of many possible solutions. There is no inherent part of a `CNN` that would restrict you in any way or hurt the 'efficiency'.

Comment: Yeah, a simple solution would be to have three classes: cat, dog, other. Then you manually label your data and train your network to output `1, 0, 0` for cats, `0, 1, 0` for dogs and `0, 0, 1` for everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labelling next class as 'other' or something like that is the simplest way to do that.

What I found, that because of many different types of images in 'other' class, training sample should be much bigger than just when differing between cats and dogs.